# R - How to iteratively change values in columns based on

Tags: r, replace, lapply

I have a data frame with 10 variables. For each column of variables 1-9, I would like to replace the values with `NA` if the tenth variable in that row is `NA`.

Before doing anything, the data looks like this:

```
var1   var2   var3    ...    var10
  1      3     3               2
  0      0     0               NA
  9      3     7               4
  0      0     0               NA
  .      .     .               .
  .      .     .               .
  .      .     .               .
```

The goal is for the data to look like this:

```
var1   var2   var3    ...    var10
  1      3     3               2
  NA     NA    NA              NA
  9      3     7               4
  NA     NA    NA              NA
  .      .     .               .
  .      .     .               .
  .      .     .               .
```

The code I am using is the following, run once for each variable 1-9:

```
data <- data %>% 
    mutate(var1= replace(var1,         # var1 on this line would be replaced by var2, var3, etc. 
                         which(is.na(var10)), NA))
```

However, I'm sure there's a better way to do this than copy/pasting that code 9 times, once for each variable 1-9.

I'm relatively new to coding in general. It seems like something based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062548/r-replace-values-in-columns) is applicable, but have not found a way to make it work. Any solutions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are using `dplyr`, then `mutate_at` can be used

```
data %>%
    mutate_at(1:9, funs(replace(., is.na(data$var10), NA)))
```

---

Or we can use `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(data[1:9], data[10], ~replace(.x, is.na(.y), NA))
```

---

This can be also done with `base R`

```
data[1:9] <- data[1:9]*NA^is.na(data$var10)
```